# Replicating a table column structure across nested child divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I am working with a piece of code that is autogenerating a nested checkbox structure based on a data structure.

Below, I have a simplification of what the nested div structure looks like:

```
<div class="tree">
    <div class="item level1">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
        <div class="children>
            <div class="item level2">
                <div class="content">
                </div>
                <div class="children>
                    <div class="item level3">
                        <div class="content">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I want add pieces of data to those `level3` nodes, but I want those pieces of data to format in a table-like way.

Here is a basic drawing:

[image: Mockup]

Note: the lines are drawn simply for ease of viewing the formatting and don't need to be in the actual view.

I want all the value 1 values to lineup to behave like columns such that each "cell" has the length of the longest div in the column so that they format easily and a user can scan down the list.

What is the best way to have these pieces of data in the `content` div the `level3` nodes while also formatting them properly? I have thought of trying to calculate the proper width of each `div` with a certain class and manually setting widths with JavaScript, but I am not sure how to grab that "proper" width so that I can adjust all the `divs`. This is also important, because we can change the values. So if one value changes, I will have to recalculate the widths.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the thing about calculating widths, why? Is there a reason for you to not just use nested <ul>-elements for this?

Comment: So, <ul> elements are not being used just because that was how it was formatted by the original developer. I could try and update it to use <ul> and <li> (or just update the css to use list display attributes), but the nesting UI already works fine.

As far as calculating widths, I want to create a pseudo-table structure within the nested tree/checklist, so that the values associated with the level3 nodes can be easily read up and down like a table would. So, I figure that manually setting widths of each piece of "data" could work for that, but I'd prefer a cleaner CSS solution if possible.